# android studio 3.0 beta 2 new project error in IRAN

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-studio-3.0

I started a new project in android studio 3.0 beta 2 but just after build without doing anything in the project I get the following error:

> Gradle sync failed: java.lang.AssertionError

and after retry this:

> Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1.
>   Could not parse POM hxxps://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.1/appcompat-v7-26.0.1.pom
>   Already seen doctype.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'hxxps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.1/appcompat-v7-26.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'hxxps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/26.0.1/appcompat-v7-26.0.1.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.0.1.
>     Required by:
>         project :app
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.0.1.
>   Could not parse POM hxxps://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/design/26.0.1/design-26.0.1.pom
>   Already seen doctype.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:design:26.0.1.
>   Could not get resource 'hxxps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/26.0.1/design-26.0.1.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'hxxps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/design/26.0.1/design-26.0.1.pom'.
>   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/75.126.118.188] failed: Connection timed out: connect

I just downloaded Java.
SDK and android studio are updated.
and I tried every type of creating a new project, with empty activity, with min SDK 26 and ......

the funny thing is everything is fine in android studio 2.3.3 and I have no problem,
also, I did the invalidate and restart and It doesn't work.
clean project doesn't work either.
sorry for my bad English :D

solve: Ok I checked with one of my friends and there was no problem in the android studio. I am in Iran which is banned by google, and I was using a proxy to connect to google but Apparently, Google checked my location and I Couldn't download some packages. all I had to do was connecting with VPN and my problem was gone.

Comment: this is not duplicate 
read my solve 
the problem is same but different cause.
and because you don't have this problem in 99% of the world this answer is nowhere to find.

Comment: you could've answered your own question (it's totally acceptable and looks better when searching)

Comment: Thanks for note
but they closed it and I cant answer my question.